# Error when using jquery redirect href

Tags: php, jquery

```
<form class="frmSearch" id="myform" method="post" action="" >
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="0" name="selection" class="type" />
    <label>Type0</label>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="selection" class="type" />
    <label>Type1</label>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

and in jquery i use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Submit form
   $('.submit').click(function(){
        var type = $('.type').val();
        document.myform.action = "index.php?type="+id;
   });  
});
```

jquery error can not get type and redirect, how to fix it ?

Comment: It almost seems to be one of those "find at least two errors in the code" questions :-)

Comment: where the value for "id" comes from ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two elements with the class type, so jQuery cannot extract the value.

The proper way to extract the value:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Submit form
   $('.submit').click(function(){
        var type = $('input:radio[name=selection]:checked').val();
        document.myform.action = "index.php?type="+type;
   });  
});
```

Also I am not sure where the id variable is coming from. plus you are not using the type value at all.

for your reference the [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) reference have an example how to get the value of radio input fields.

Comment: @DaDaDom: did not catch the id stuff, thanks for the comment ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript code is wrong: You are storing the value of the selected `.type` in a variable called `type` but in the redirect string you are trying to get the requested value from a variable called `id`. Just correct the line to read like

```
document.myform.action = "index.php?type=" + type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Gonna fail using class as selector. Try with name

```
$('input:radio[name=selection]:checked').val();
```